# How to insert a column in a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This seem to be a trivial question, yet I did not find the answer I am looking for.
I have a 2D array say:

```
a = np.array([[1,3,5],[2,4,6]])
```

And another column

```
b = np.array([9,11])
bt = np.reshape(b, (2,1))
```

I would like to add/append the `bt` column at the zero column of array `a`. I tried using `numpy.insert`:

```
tt = np.insert(a,0,bt,axis=1)
```

But the result is:

```
array([[ 9, 11,  1,  3,  5],
       [ 9, 11,  2,  4,  6]])
```

What I want is:

```
array([[ 9, 1,  3,  5],
       [ 11,  2,  4,  6]])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy.column_stack` to do that:

```
a = np.array([[1,3,5],[2,4,6]])
b = np.array([9,11])
np.column_stack((b, a))

array([[ 9,  1,  3,  5],
       [11,  2,  4,  6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either directly use `b`:

```
tt = np.insert(a, 0, b, axis=1)
print tt

[[ 9  1  3  5]
 [11  2  4  6]]
```

Or, if you are starting with something shaped like `bt`, transpose it:

```
tt = np.insert(a, 0, bt.T, axis=1)
print tt

[[ 9  1  3  5]
 [11  2  4  6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative alongside `np.hstack` you can play with [`indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) :

```
>>> c=np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.shape[1]+1))
>>> c[::,0]=b
>>> c[::,1:]=a
>>> c
array([[  9.,   1.,   3.,   5.],
       [ 11.,   2.,   4.,   6.]])
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. But I am not fully following.
What are:
>>>c[::,0]=b
>>> c[::,1:]=a

Comment: @Arcticpython its column assignment ! `c[::,0]=b`  will assign `b` on the firs column of `c` and `c[::,1:]=a` will assign the `a` on the second column of c to end